# because in some apps an install button appears from the search and in my app it doesn't

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the Play Store, and when I search for it, only the result of my app is displayed. However, when I search for other apps, it shows me additional information and even a button to install them.

I have attached the necessary proof."
[image: image how my app looks]

[image: Image how I want it to look]